# Reading EEPROM addresses in Python and perform operations

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pattern-matching, eeprom

I am currently trying to match pattern for an eeprom dump text file to locate a certain address and then traverse 4 steps once I hit upon in the search. I have tried the following code for finding the pattern

```
regexp_list = ('A1 B2')
line = open("dump.txt", 'r').read()
pattern = re.compile(regexp_list)

matches = re.findall(pattern,line)

for match in matches:
    print(match)
```

this scans the dump for `A1 B2` and displays if found. I need to add more such addresses in search criteria for ex: `'C1 B2', 'D1  F1'`.
I tried making the `regexp_list` as a list and not a tuple, but it didn't work.

This is one of the problem. Next when I hit upon the search, I want to traverse 4 places and then read the address from there on (See below).

Input:

```
0120   86 1B 00 A1  B2 FF 15 A0  05 C2 D1 E4  00 25 04 00
```

Here when the search finds `A1 B2` pattern, I want to move 4 places i.e to save data from `C2 D1 E4` from the dump.

Expected Output:

```
C2 D1 E4
```

I hope the explanation was clear.

#

Thanks to @kcorlidy

Here's the final piece of code which I had to enter to delete the addresses in the first column.

```
newtxt = (text.split("A0 05")[1].split()[4:][:5])

for i in newtxt:
    if len(i) > 2:
        newtxt.remove(i)
```

and so the full code looks like

```
import re

text = open('dump.txt').read()

regex = r"(A1\s+B2)(\s+\w+){4}((\s+\w{2}(\s\w{4})?){3})"

for ele in re.findall(regex,text,re.MULTILINE):

    print(" ".join([ok for ok in ele[2].split() if len(ok) == 2]))

print(text.split("A1 B2")[1].split()[4:][:5])

#selects the next 5 elements in the array including the address in 1st col
newtxt = (text.split("A1 B2")[1].split()[4:][:5])

for i in newtxt:
    if len(i) > 2:
        newtxt.remove(i)
```

Input:

```
0120 86 1B 00 00 C1 FF 15 00 00 A1 B2 00 00 00 00 C2
0130 D1 E4 00 00 FF 04 01 54 00 EB 00 54 89 B8 00 00
```

Output:

```
C2 0130 D1 E4 00

C2 D1 E4 00
```

Comment: Check https://regexr.com/44htl and use the last 3 groups for getting C2 D1 E4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regex can extract text, but also you can complete it through split text.

Regex:

1. `(A1\s+B2)` string start with `A1` + `one or more space` + `B2`
2. `(\s+\w+){4}` move 4 places
3. `((\s+\w+(\s+\w{4})?){3})` extract 3 group of string, and There may be 4 unneeded characters in the group. Then combine them into one.

Split:

Note: If you have a very long text or multiple lines, don't use this way.

1. `text.split("A1  B2")[1]` split text to two part. the after is we need
2. `.split()` split by blank space and became the list `['FF', '15', 'A0', '05', 'C2', 'D1', 'E4', '00', '25', '04', '00']`
3. `[4:][:3]` move 4 places, and select the first three

Test code:

```
import re

text = """0120   86 1B 00 A1  B2 FF 15 A0  05 C2 D1 E4  00 25 04 00 
0120 86 1B 00 00 C1 FF 15 00 00 A1 B2 00 00 00 00 C2
0130 D1 E4 00 00 FF 04 01 54 00 EB 00 54 89 B8 00 00 """
regex = r"(A1\s+B2)(\s+\w+){4}((\s+\w{2}(\s\w{4})?){3})"

for ele in re.findall(regex,text,re.MULTILINE):
    #remove the string we do not need, such as blankspace, 0123, \n
    print(" ".join([ok for ok in ele[2].split() if len(ok) == 2]))

print( text.split("A1  B2")[1].split()[4:][:3] )
```

Output

```
C2 D1 E4
C2 D1 E4
['C2', 'D1', 'E4']
```

Comment: text = open('dump.txt').read()
regex = r"(A1\s+B2)(\s+\w{2}){4}((\s+\w{2}){3})"
print(re.search(regex, text).group(3).lstrip())

print(text.split("A1  B2")[1].split()[4:][:3])

Comment: I have adapted your code to read a file and search for the string. it works well. Top! However this is only valid if there are enough number of array elements to the right. If I want to traverse the array on the next row, can I do it ? see my ex below :

Comment: 0120   86 1B 00 00  C1 FF 15 00  00 A1 B2 00  00 00 00 C2

Comment: 0130   D1 E4 00 00  FF 04 01 54  00 EB 00 54  89 B8 00 00

Comment: when I need to traverse from A1, B2 next four places and if there are no four elements in this array, i need to read from next two from the next row. Can we do this ?

Comment: Of course, but i am not sure whether `C2 0130 D1` is what you want. @crazybyPy

Comment: No .. I would want to read C2, D1, E4. Which means that I need to take one element from the current row and next two elements from the next. "0120, 0130" are the address' which I need to ignore.

Comment: @crazybyPy I modified my regex for this case.